# How do I make Materialize's Tooltips sticky to floating action buttons?

Tags: html, css, tooltip, materialize, floating-action-button

I am adding [Materialize's tooltips](https://materializecss.com/tooltips.html#!) to [floating action buttons](https://materializecss.com/floating-action-button.html), but the tooltips are not sticking next to the buttons as I scroll down the page.

```
 <div class="fixed-action-btn">
  <a class="btn-floating btn-large turquoise tooltipped pulse" data-position="left" data-tooltip="Learn More">
    <i class="large material-icons">add_circle_outline</i>
  </a>
  <ul>
    <li><a class="btn-floating blue tooltipped" data-position="left" data-tooltip="I'm interested in staying up to date!"><i class="material-icons">favorite</i></a></li>
    <li><a class="btn-floating green tooltipped" data-position="left" data-tooltip="I'm interested in funding this!"><i class="material-icons">business_center</i></a></li>
    <li><a class="btn-floating yellow tooltipped" data-position="left" data-tooltip="I'm interested in beta testing!"><i class="material-icons">pets</i></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I have attached two screenshots - one at the top of the page how I'd like the tooltips to be displayed wherever I have scrolled to on the page, and how it currently looks when I scroll down.

Many thanks!

[image: How I'd like it to look]
[image: How it currently looks when I scroll down]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this, I dug around in the tooltip github documentation to find a function called `_positionTooltip`. It appears that the code does not have a scroll listener, so in the example below, I created a scroll listener that calls the _positionTooltip function.

I was able to get the tooltips to stay positioned correctly like this:

You can also view it here: https://codepen.io/tuffant21/pen/mdJggpw

```js
let tooltipInstances;

window.onload = function() {
  M.FloatingActionButton.init(document.querySelectorAll('.fixed-action-btn'));
  tooltipInstances = M.Tooltip.init(document.querySelectorAll('.tooltipped'));

  // You should remove this event listener when it is no longer needed.
  window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
    for (let i = 0; i < tooltipInstances.length; ++i) {
      tooltipInstances[i]._positionTooltip();
    }
  });
}
```

```css
/* set body height to mimic content on a page */
body {
  height: 5000px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<div class="fixed-action-btn">
  <a class="btn-floating btn-large turquoise pulse tooltipped fixed" data-position="left" data-tooltip="Learn More">
    <i class="large material-icons">add_circle_outline</i>
  </a>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a class="btn-floating blue tooltipped" data-position="left" data-tooltip="I'm interested in staying up to date!">
        <i class="material-icons">favorite</i></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="btn-floating green tooltipped" data-position="left" data-tooltip="I'm interested in funding this!">
        <i class="material-icons">business_center</i></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="btn-floating yellow tooltipped" data-position="left" data-tooltip="I'm interested in beta testing!">
        <i class="material-icons">pets</i></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't know a lot of javascript, but this doesn't work too well for me. The tooltip gets attached to the floating action button, but when scrolling sometimes it gets stuck for a bit in a previous position. Could the loop be more efficient so that doesn't happen? Or is something else problematic, because in your example it worked nicely, but the page was completely empty.